# Cannot rotate angle of LAS dataset using spTransform

Tags: r, lidar

I previously was able to adjust the angle of my las data using the below function I made. No idea why it has started giving issues? Has spTransform changed?

I am using the code below in R:

````
rotatelas <- function(x, angle=0) {
  y <- x; projection(y) <- "+proj=aeqd +ellps=sphere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0"
  spTransform(y,  paste0("+proj=aeqd +ellps=sphere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=", -angle))
}

las1<-rotatelas(f1raw,6)

#Warning message:
#Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass) : 
#assignment of an object of class “CRS” is not valid for @‘crs’ in an object of class “LAS”; is(value, "crs") is not TRUE```
````